# como hacer para que no me sobreescriba lo que le envio de una consulta de sql en un textview cuando le mando varios valores

Tags: java, android

hago una consulta en android y la guardo en variables pero estas me sobrescriben y me muestran nada mas lo ultimo como hacer para que no me sobrescriban y aparezca toda la información lo estoy realizando en un `TextView` en `Android Studio`.

```
while (rs.next()){
  Tipo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tipo);
  Sucursal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sucursal);
  Cliente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Cliente);
  Tipo.setText(rs.getString(1));
  Sucursal.setText(rs.getString(3));
  Cliente.setText(rs.getString(4));    
 }
```

Comment: Agrega el código que has tratado, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: este es el codigo donde utilizo el while para que me recorra toda la tabla y lo alamaceno en cliente tipo y sucursal pero solo me muestra el ultimo valor

Comment: gracias @user126636 recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar más información mediante el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/260357/edit), agregué respuesta, no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener primero el texto que ya se encuentra en el `TextView` mediante el método:

```
getText().toString()
```

y posteriormente puedes concatenar este texto con el que se obtiene del cursor, puedes usar `+=` :

```
   //Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
   String textoTipo = Tipo.getText().toString();
   //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
   Tipo.setText(textoTipo += rs.getString(1));
```

---

Este sería el código :

```
while (rs.next()){
  Tipo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tipo);
  Sucursal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sucursal);
  Cliente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Cliente);

  //Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
  String textoTipo = Tipo.getText().toString();
  //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
  Tipo.setText(textoTipo += rs.getString(1) + "\n");

  //Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
  String textoSucursal = Sucursal.getText().toString();
  //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
  Sucursal.setText(textoSucursal += rs.getString(3) + "\n");

  //Obtiene texto actual en TextView.
  String textoCliente = Cliente.getText().toString();
  //Al texto actual agrega el texto que se encuentra en el cursor.
  Cliente.setText(textoCliente += rs.getString(4) + "\n");    
 }
```

Comment: con ese codigo ya no se estara sobreescribiendo el valor

Comment: muchísimas gracias ahora si me los agrega todos los campos pero me los agrega sin formato como puedo darle formato osea que valla dando un salto de linea para cada registro

Comment: muy fácil, recuerda que puedes agregar "\n", que indica salto de linea, revisa mi actualización.

Comment: muchisimas gracias enserioooo me ayudo bastanteeeeee con eso

Comment: Recuerda, agregar información a tus preguntas y realizarlas en base a [ask] te aseguro siempre tendrás ayuda  de los miembros de la comunidad la cual solucionará tus preguntas, realiza el [tour] del sitio y marca la respuesta como correcta si es que te ayudo a solucionar, saludos.

Comment: muy bien muchisimas gracias por la ayuda me sirvio muchisimo